# Objectify+Eclipse+Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library: "Variable does not conform to style guide"

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

What I am using: Eclipse, Java, Objectify, Google App Engine SDK

I am sorry if this question was already solved. But I could not find any solution. Here is the situation:

I was trying for about 3 weeks to make my project work. At first, I had an Android Project. Then, with Google Eclipse Plugin, I generated an App Engine Backend (on Eclipse) and started to work with JPA. However, I had too many problems regarding relationships. I just lost time and patience. So, I decided to move to objectify.

I built my classes following all the steps of Objectify's documentation. I defined my Endpoints replacing the previous code (that used JPA) by a new one. objectify and guava jars are both on WEB-INF/lib and inside the build path.

The problem: when I try to generate the Cloud Endpoint Client Libraries, I got this error:

There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes:

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 
400 Bad Request
{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Variable  does not conform to style guide"}]}}
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Variable  does not conform to style guide"}]}}
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:144)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Variable  does not conform to style guide"}]}}
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1054)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:53)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:142)
    ... 4 more
Root exception:
com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmGenerationException: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Variable  does not conform to style guide"}]}}
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:144)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createSwarmApi(SwarmApiCreator.java:258)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmServiceCreator.create(SwarmServiceCreator.java:444)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.GenerateSwarmApiAction$1.run(GenerateSwarmApiAction.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Variable  does not conform to style guide"}]}}
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1054)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.postRequest(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:53)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.CloudClientLibGenerator.generateClientLib(CloudClientLibGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.appengine.swarm.wizards.helpers.SwarmApiCreator.createClientLibFromApiConfig(SwarmApiCreator.java:142)
    ... 4 more
```

Some examples (including the Entity Registration). I will suppress package, imports and getters/setters. If anyone knows how to help, I would really appreciate. If there is any code I should put here, please let me know.

User.java

```
@Entity
    public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Index
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    private String friendCode;

    @Load
    private List<Ref<Group>> groups = new ArrayList<Ref<Group>>(); //groups that a User can be simple member

    //...
    }
```

Group.java

```
@Entity
public class Group {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    private String name;

    @Load
    @Index
    private Ref<User> owner; // Owner of the group. The creator.
```

OfyService.java

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

public class OfyService {
    static {
        factory().register(Group.class);
        factory().register(User.class);      
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

UserEndpoint.java

```
import static com.uandq.lychee.OfyService.ofy;
@Api(name = "sampleEndpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "sample.com", ownerName = "sample.com", packagePath = ""))
public class UserEndpoint {


    @ApiMethod(name = "listUser")
    public List<User> listUser() {
        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
        result = ofy().load().type(User.class).list();
        return result;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "getUser")
    public User getUser(@Named Long id) {
        User user = ofy().load().type(User.class).id(id).now();
        return user;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "insertUser")
    public User insertUser(User user) {
        ofy().save().entity(user).now();
        return user;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "removeUser")
    public void removeUser(@Named Long id) {
        ofy().delete().type(User.class).id(id).now();
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "findUserByPhoneNumber")
    public User findUserByPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phone) {

        User user = ofy().load().type(User.class)
                .filter("phoneNumber ==", phone).first().now();

        return user;
    }
}
```

GroupEndpoint.java

```
import static com.uandq.lychee.OfyService.ofy;

@Api(name = "sampleEndpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "sample.com", ownerName = "sample.com", packagePath = ""))
public class GroupEndpoint {

    @ApiMethod(name = "listGroup")
    public List<Group> listGroup() {
        List<Group> result = new ArrayList<Group>();
        result = ofy().load().type(Group.class).list();
        return result;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "getGroup")
    public Group getGroup(@Named Long id) {
        Group group = ofy().load().type(Group.class).id(id).now();
        return group;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "insertGroup")
    public Group insertGroup(Group group) {
        ofy().save().entity(group).now();
        return group;
    }

    @ApiMethod(name = "removeGroup")
    public void removeGroup(@Named Long id) {
        ofy().delete().type(Group.class).id(id).now();
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sample.GroupEndpoint, com.sample.UserEndpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In addition, I tried now to generate the Endpoint libs following these steps: 
Generating a client library for Android using endpoints.sh
via Terminal. And it did not work as well. I still get:

```
Error: 400 Bad Request

{"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Variable  does not conform to style guide"}]}}
```

Any help is welcome.
The question was also posted on: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/objectify-appengine/981f4LlXscg

Comment: You probably want to add the google-cloud-endpoints tag; the experts most likely to understand that error message will be watching that tag.

Comment: Oh, I just did that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the extra error details that the Terminal outputs? 
As per the answer at this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568970/generating-the-api-metadata-for-cloud-endpoints-classes-failed

Comment: Hey, actually I solved it. I just don't have reputation, so I cannot post my answer until 10pm :/

Comment: That's good news - don't forget to post your answer!

Comment: I just posted. If you can tick as solved, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question now is Solved.

Solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en-GB#!topic/objectify-appengine/981f4LlXscg

I found the problem. Actually I followed everything on this link https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android . Then, there is:

> **Most parameter types must be serializable** because JSON requires that
>   the objects be serializable. You may also use any JavaBean, which
>   includes anything from your model, since your model objects should
>   conform to the JavaBean standard as described above. 
>   **A limited set of**
>   **types need not be serializable**, but must be annotated with @Named.
>   These are the types: String, int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, long/Long.

In my endpoints, some parameters were using the annotation @Named in a wrong way: without the actual name of the parameter. I don't even need to implement Serializable. I just replaced:

```
public User getUser(@Named Long id)
```

by

```
public User getUser(@Named("id") Long id)
```

And all the others @Named parameters. Now I am able to generate the Endpoint libs.

Comment: Just faced the issue and would like to comment that one will get this error if the annotation contains a string that contains a space character.