# How to send complicated entity from android client to Google AppEngine endpoint?

Tags: java, android, json, google-app-engine, objectify

I have problem with my app-endpoint project. I need to send my entity object from android application to endpoint but I really can not find it how to do it properly. My entity object use Objectify if it is important.

**First try**

When I tried pass my entity object as parameter of @ApiMethod I got compilation error about

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
> There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: Parameterized type com.package.NestedData<com.package.AnotherData> not supported.
```

So I can not use there generic types.

**Second try**

I also tried to send this object as Json object (string parameter), but i got

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: 413 FULL head
```

Ok, too long string... is there a nice way to send that?

**Third try**

Last thing I have tried is serializing object and send an array of bytes. It also not working for me.

- @ApiMethod can not have byte[] as parameter. I got message that byte[] is illegal parameter type.
- Blob parameter type. It wont compile. Error:

  > Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
  >   There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: 400 Bad Request
  >   {"error": {"message": "Bad Request", "code": 400, "errors": [{"message": "api exception", "debug_info": "Cannot decode JSON Schema for: {u'parameterName': u'resource'}"}]}}

**Conclusion**

I have no idea how to do that. Please help me figure that out. Thanks!

**Example code**

Entities. This is example structure, but very similar to my real object. They have to look like this because they are parsed from another json (by GSON), so i cannot change structure.

```
@Entity
public class Example {
    @Id long id;
    String name;
    NestedData<AnotherData> data;
} 

@Entity
class AnotherData {
    @Id long id;
    String name;
    int value;
}

@Entity
class NestedData<T> {
    List<T> list;
}
```

Comment: Any success in solving this problem? Unless I'm missing something I don't understand why this is marked as a duplicate to another post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [valid parameter type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types). This question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568970/generating-the-api-metadata-for-cloud-endpoints-classes-failed), which coincidentally shows a user attempting to use `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Blob`, as you are.